# How to make a timer and a loop in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, timer, infinite-loop

I need some help completing my .bat file.

So what I wanna do is that after the program has started I wanna leave it running for like 1min then I want it to close the program and then run it agian for 1min. So it will be loop. I'm a complete novice on this so all help is appreciated.

This is what i currently have:

```
    @echo off
    color a
    echo ProHaxor1337 Initialised
    color b
    :start
    start (Program Name Here)
    GOTO start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, assuming that there is only one instance of *programname.exe* allowed on the system:

```
@echo off
color a
echo ProHaxor1337 Initialised
color b
:start
start programname.exe
REM Delay using ping to localhost (1 ping per second)
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 60 > nul
REM Kill the process forcefully.
taskkill /im programname.exe /f
GOTO start
```

Comment: alternative wait method >timeout /T 1 , this does not use (any real) cpu effort. Depends on the OS though which the question does not provide.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been programming CMD too long and sometimes I get stuck on the old methods.  I never liked using ping.  It looks like timeout is native to Windows 7/2008.

Comment: I would prefer to add /nobreak after timeout too, as to prevent any keystrokes that maybe accidentally typed by host that may lead to unexpected results.